# R: how to find the first digit in a string

Tags: regex, r

```
    string = "ABC3JFD456"
```

Suppose I have the above string, and I wish to find what the first digit in the string is and store its value. In this case, I would want to store the value 3 (since it's the first-occuring digit in the string). `grepl("\\d", string)` only returns a logical value, but does not tell me anything about where or what the first digit is. Which regular expression should I use to find the value of the first digit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Base R

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("\\d", string))
## [1] "3"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first(string, regex = "\\d")
## [1] "3"
```

Or using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "\\d")
## [1] "3"
```

Answer (score 7):

**1) sub** Try `sub` with the indicated regular expression which takes the shortest string until a digit, a digit and then everything following and replaces it with the digit:

```
sub(".*?(\\d).*", "\\1", string)
```

giving:

```
[1] "3"
```

This also works if `string` is a vector of strings.

**2) strapplyc** It would also be possible to use `strapplyc` from [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) in which case an even simpler regular expression could be used:

```
strapplyc(string, "\\d", simplify = TRUE)[1]
```

giving the same or use this which gives the same answer again but also works if `string` is a vector of strings:

```
sapply(strapplyc(string, "\\d"), "[[", 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the locations of the digits

```
tmp <- gregexpr("[0-9]", string)
iloc <- unlist(tmp)[1]
```

Extract the first digit

```
as.numeric(substr(string,iloc,iloc))
```

Using regexpr is simpler

```
tmp<-regexpr("[0-9]",string)
if(tmp[[1]]>=0) {
    iloc <- tmp[1]
    num <- as.numeric(substr(string,iloc,iloc))
}
```

Comment: Or just use `regexpr`, which will only return the first hit of [0-9].

Comment: Yes, regexpr is better

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
string = c("ABC3JFD456", "ARST4DS324")

re_matches(string,
  rex(
    capture(name = "first_number", digit)
    )
  )

#>   first_number
#> 1            3
#> 2            4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> which( sapply( strsplit(string, ""),  grepl, patt="[[:digit:]]"))[1]
[1] 4
```

Or

```
> gregexpr("[[:digit:]]", string)[[1]][1]
[1] 4
```

So:

```
> splstr[[1]][ which( sapply( splstr,  grepl, patt="[[:digit:]]"))[1] ]
[1] "3"
```

Note that a full result from a gregexpr call is a list, hence the need to extract its first element with "[[":

```
>  gregexpr("[[:digit:]]", string)
[[1]]
[1]  4  8  9 10
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that I have the index, how can I extract the digit from the string? `string[4]` will not work

Comment: `regmatches` as used by David Arenburg's answer would be the preferred base R method of extracting regex matches from strings I think. Also, `regexpr` would remove the need to subset the results of `gregexpr`

Comment: Yep, it's true. I'm a regex clutz.

Answer (score 0):

A `gsub` solution that is based on replacing the substrings preceding and following the first digit with the empty string:

```
gsub("^\\D*(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d).*", "", string, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "3"
```